# Contentful: Can one allow references and native field-types in the same group of items?

Tags: content-management-system, contentful

I think the answer is "no" but any ideas appreciated...

Let's I have a content type "Article", another content type called "Video" and another called "Chart." In Article, I want a field called "ArticleItems" that can accept one or more entries of type "Video" or type "Chart." Easy enough -- I create a Reference field, allow it to be multi-select and choose "Video" and "Chart" as the valid content types for the linked entries.

But I would also like "Rich Text" or "Media" to be a valid choices for "ArticleItems." In other words, not references to an entry, just a plain field, such that "ArticleItems" is mix-and-match between a selection of entries and a selection of native field types.

Can't do it, right? I would have to create my own "Rich Text" content type with one single Rich Text field, right?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contentful DevRel here.

I think you're correct with that one. Currently, a field can not switch between a native field type or a reference.

> I would have to create my own "Rich Text" content type with one single Rich Text field, right?

That's one approach, but I think the other way around might be a better choice. Use a Richtext field. It allows you to reference entries and fluent text if needed. :)

Comment: Thanks! I think it would be useful to have mix-and-match capability as described and/or define a field as one or more Richtext/Text/Media the same as we can with References.